# How do I get the uploaded image to go to a unique User Uid on Firebase instead of a declared User Uid?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

[image]

I am trying to get an image uploaded to a unique user uid instead of the one thats specified on the screen so that any authenticated user that gets there own user uid can have access or be able to upload photos?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `currentUser` to declare the `uid` in the storage path. Here is an similar example:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future uploadFile() async {
    String photoURL = await StorageService.uploadFile(
        'users/${_auth.currentUser.uid}/${Path.basename(_image.path)}', _image);

    await _auth.currentUser.updateProfile(photoURL: photoURL);
    UserService.updateUser({'photoURL': photoURL});
    _auth.currentUser.reload();

    setState(() {
      isImageLoading = false;
    });
  }
```